# ECONNREFUSED in docker with nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, stripe-payments

I'm having a problem while writing my unit tests for my node application.
From my backend I contact Stripe APIs and Paypal APIs, my unit tests crashes every time I try to run my tests inside the docker because of a connection problem.
When I run the same tests from my local machine they pass without problems.
So I think this has to be with the ports exposure but I'm not sure because I'm not an expert.
This is the command I'm using to start my container:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /Users/nicolovanzo/Documents/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -v /Users/nicolovanzo/Documents/work/storm/backups/firestore:/var/jenkins_home/firestore  -v /Users/nicolovanzo/Documents/work/storm/firebase_keys/dev.json:/var/jenkins_home/firebase_keys/dev.json jenkins/jenkins
```

In my code whenever I try to contact an API outside of my docker it crashes saying:

```
    data: { code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

I can't find any solution online so I think you can help me. I would be really happy if you can find a solution or lead me to it.

Comment: For unit tests, can you use a mock version of the API?  What URL or other endpoint are you actually trying to call?  (`docker run -p` only affects connections into the container and has no effect on outbound calls.)

Comment: No matter what endpoint I call. I'm getting the same behaviour for Paypal too. I'm trying to use their SDK so this code here: ```session = await this.stripe.checkout.sessions.create(options as any);``` or even in ```const price = await stripe.prices.retrieve(id);```

Comment: I think the problem might be related to dns (https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services) resolution inside of the docker container. 
Maybe trying a dns of 8.8.8.8 might help.

Comment: Holy ding dude, I'm not getting that error anymore so that's probably the solution. I will post it as solution tomorrow when I will be able to test it more at work

Comment: I've tried to add the dns following the documentation you provided but that's not working. Sometimes the error comes again but not everytime I run my tests...I don't know what can be the cause of this